# How to assign the value of a chosen option from a dropdown to a variable in jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I have a dropdown in jsp:

```
<select name="tableName">
<c:forEach var="dropDown" items="${dropDown}">
<c:forEach var="valuesInRows" items="${dropDown.valuesInRows}">
<c:forEach var="valuesInRow" items="${valuesInRows}" varStatus="loop">                                        
<c:if test="${loop.index %2 != 0}">
<option><c:out value="${valuesInRow}"></c:out></option>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Then I want to add the chosen variable as a parameter to a url in the same jsp. How to do it? Thank you!

```
<s:url var="url_list" value="/spravochnik/list">
<s:param name="tableName" value="${tableName}"/>
</s:url>
```

This one doesn't work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Well I recommend you to use javascript you can put an Id to your select and do the following function:

```
function myFunction(){
       var select = document.getElementById("selectId");
       var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
       document.getElementById("newID").value = value;
    }
```

and then if you want to put an id here

```
<s:url var="url_list" value="/spravochnik/list">
    <s:param id="newID" name="tableName" value=""/>
</s:url>
```

The last thing is to put an event to the select

```
<select name="tableName" onchange="myFunction()"> 
<c:forEach var="dropDown" items="${dropDown}"> 
<c:forEach var="valuesInRows" items="${dropDown.valuesInRows}"> 
<c:forEach var="valuesInRow" items="${valuesInRows}" varStatus="loop">                              
<c:if test="${loop.index %2 != 0}"> 
<option><c:out value="${valuesInRow}"></c:out> </option> 
</c:if> 
</c:forEach> 
</c:forEach> 
</c:forEach> 
</select>
```